# Swift: For loops (with if statements) at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, for-loop

I have two arrays:

`tasks = [a,b,c]` and `clType = [a,a,b,c,c,c]`

The array `tasks` is the same as `clType` but I removed the duplicates using a for loop with if statements.

Now I want to create a tableview with sections, where every section is one element of the `tasks` array. In this section the elements of the `clType` array should be stored under the right section. I tried to configure this with the following for loop(s):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    print(clType)
    for index in tasks.indices{
      if indexPath.section == index{
        for index1 in clType.indices{
            if clType[index1] == tasks[index]{
             cell.textLabel?.text = clType[index1] + ": " + taskName[index1] + "  //  " + dateStamp[index1] //Taskname and dateStamp are arrays with a matching index with regard to clType.
            }
        }
    }
}

    return cell
}
```

I think I'm already heading in the right direction, but the tableview isn't displaying the right thing. What I now see is three section (=correct), but every row in that section is the same. Of course the letters (a,b,c) are the same in every section, but the `taskName` and `dateStamp` should be different.

How can this be fixed. I know i'm missing something in the logic, but what?

Comment: Do you need the outer for-loop? Can't you do "index = tasks[indexPath.section]" ?

Comment: If i'm understanding your question correctly: I want to have `index1` in the end, because that would determine the correct index to display of my array. So that would be the inner loop?

Comment: Just to get this correct, you want 'tasks' to be the section headings and 'clType' to be rows within the correct section of 'tasks'.  What criteria determines in which section we should sort the 'clType'?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The criterium is that the string of `cltype` == the string of `tasks`. So every 'a'-row should be in the 'a'-section, accompanied with the information from other arrays `taskName` and `dateStamp`.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem by myself. It was caused by the fact that for every row the loop found a 'match' at the first possible index that was the same as the "section title". I added the following:

```
....
if clType[index1] == tasks[index]{
         cell.textLabel?.text = clType[index1] + ": " + taskName[index1] + "  //  " + dateStamp[index1] //Taskname and dateStamp are arrays with a matching index with regard to clType.
clType[index1] = "" //THIS IS WHAT I ADDED
        }
```

So the next time it looped over the array, there wasn't a match at that index, but at the next one. This is what I wanted.